# to wave something in the air

Tags: meaning, clarification

If you wave at someone, you'd use zuwinken.

However it doesn't feel right to use zuwinken if I were for example waving an object.

How would I then describe if I were to:

1. wave a flag
2. wave a kite around or better worded, to fly a kite
3. wave a piece of paper
4. wave frantically for help from the ocean if i were drowning
5. wave like a baby holding a rattle

It feels like numbers 1, 3 and 5 might all use a similar verb but I can't imagine it would be with zuwinken.

Comment: most of your sentences can be directly translated by just pasting the phrase in google translate. And every dictionary will give you a lot of translations of "wave" in addition to "zuwinken". As there are: schwenken, winken, wehen, flattern... Just check [Linguee](https://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/wave+a+flag.html) and follow the links behind the translations to get "back- translations" of the different possibilities to find out, what exactly they mean.

Comment: https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/de/%0A%20%20%20%20wave%20a%20flag%0A%20%20%20%20wave%20a%20kite%20around%20or%20better%20worded%2C%20fly%20a%20kite%0A%20%20%20%20wave%20a%20piece%20of%20paper%0A%20%20%20%20wave%20frantically%20for%20help%20from%20the%20ocean%20if%20i%20were%20drowning%0A%20%20%20%20wave%20like%20a%20baby%20holding%20a%20rattle%0A

Comment: You could conceivably use Google translate for everything, but it doesn't teach one the subtleties of each verb ans why one would use them in the given situations. As per the answer given below, it seems like different verbs could be used which was the why I posed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Eine Flagge schwenken
2. Einen Drachen steigen lassen (I never heard the expression 'wave a kite' for the action of flying a kite - is this about 'pumping' a kite by repeatedly tugging the line?)
3. Mit einem Blatt Papier (or 'Stück Papier' if it's irregular) wedeln (depends on the intent and/or motion : 'wedeln' would imply a continued motion to either move air or catch someone's attention)
4. Panisch winken um Hilfe herbeizuholen (though realisitcally, while drowning, there is no waving of arms ('winken') but 'rudern' (moving frantically in random wave/swim/hold patterns)
5. Ein Kind schüttelt eine Rassel. / Ein Kind rasselt. / Ein Kind wedelt mit einer Rassel (implying the child does not actually produce a continued rattling, but rather is just inexpertly waving the rattle)

'Mit X jemandem zuwinken' works for any X that can be waved around, but will always imply 'to wave at someone with X', so it would work with flags, kites, papers, rattles, etc. but only if the intent was such.

Just 'Jemandem zuwinken' will work in any case that involves waving to get or keep someones attention or to confer that they have your attention, so it would work in case 4, but the action itself does not go well with drowning, for technical reasons.

Comment: die Übersetzung von **5: wave like a baby holding a rattle** stimmt nicht

Comment: @Iris Falls damit gemint ist, dass ich nicht 'wave like a baby holding a rattle' direkt übersetzt habe : Das war so gedacht, der Ursprungssatz ist ja schon Quark.

Comment: ja, aber dann solltest du das dazuschreiben, eventuell den englischen Satz korrigieren, und nicht einfach eine falsche Übersetzung hinschreiben.